# Including Boto Library in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am in search of how to include the Boto library in an Elastic Beanstalk instance. I was under the impression I had to specify it in `.ebextensions`. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work (see below).

python.config:

```
packages:
    python:
        Flask: []
        Boto: []
option_settings:
...AWS key redacted...
```

Code:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
```

Error message:
    `ImportError: No module named boto`

Am I missing anything in the config file? Is there additional things I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

The package name of [boto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto) is lower case in fact, so adjusting that might already solve your problem.

Alternatively you might want to try the apparently recommended way for [Customizing and Configuring a Python Container](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_custom_container.html) via the typical `requirements.txt` file and `pip` instead, see 2):

> Create a **requirements.txt** file and place it in the top-level directory
>   of your source bundle. A typical python application will have
>   dependencies on other third-party Python packages. In Python, pip is
>   the standard way of installing packages. Pip has a feature that allows
>   you to specify all the packages you need (as well as their versions)
>   in a single requirements file. For more information about the
>   requirements file, go to [Requirements files](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html). The following is an
>   example requirements.txt file for Django.
>
> ```
> Django==1.4.1
> MySQL-python==1.2.3
> ```

So in your case that might currently be:

```
Flask==0.9
boto==2.9.2
```

This is also illustrated like so in [Deploying a Python Application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk Using the Elastic Beanstalk Console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_python_console.html).

Answer (score 0):

The library 'boto' is installed by default on beanstalk's AMI.

If you're using the default elastic beanstalk role (IAM), then you need not put those sensitive-information like keys on your config.

Something like this just works directly:

```
# .ebexetensions/boto-testing.config
commands:
  boto-testing:
    command: python -c "import boto;boto.connect_s3().get_bucket('my-private-bucket').get_key('secretfolder/secretfile.txt').get_contents_to_filename('/path/to/save/it');"
```